# Having ANSI_PADDING set on but still cannot insert padded with spaces values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have ANSI_PADDING set ON on my columns.
But when I insert string with different number of spaces at the end of my string `'SS  '` and `'SS        '` I get duplicate key in object error.

In SQL server I see my strings without spaces at the end.

Any idea why SQL still trims my strings and deals with them as the same string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626) says it very clearly:

> The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect whether SQL Server pads
>   strings before it compares them. SET ANSI_PADDING only affects whether
>   trailing blanks are trimmed from values being inserted into a table,
>   **so it affects storage but not comparisons.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Alter your table after creation

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
-- alter the table to add the columns that need ANDI passing
```

> ANSI_PADDING on setting affects only the definition of new columns. After the column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting when the column was created. Existing columns are not affected by a later change to this setting.